# variable arg functions and errors

Tags: c

I have a variable arg function with the following signature --

int G( int a, char *b, int c, ... );

The caller can pass in an option int d if they so choose. If not we use the default for d.

There is no relationship between (a,b,c) and d. What I mean by that is neither of the parameters a, b or c tell me if d is going to be passed in or not.

In my code I am doing this --

```
va_list valist;    
int input_d = 0;
va_start( valist, c);
input_d = va_arg(va_list, int);
```

Is it possible for va_arg() function to return a garbage value if the caller only passed in a, b and c (only three parameters)?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, the receiving function has no way of knowing how many parameters were passed, if any.  The `printf()` function figures out how many parameters it was passed by parsing the format string, and if the number of format specifiers in the format string does not agree with the number of parameters following the format string, `printf()` blissfully prints garbage.

Comment: Possible? It is undefined behavior, so garbage is certainly allowed. In fact in most modern implementations garage it is not only possible but the most likely result by far, returning whatever happened to be on the stack. I suspect that you will need to change your function signature to allow the argument count to be inferred, or preferably a second interface with the additional argument. Or possibly some nasty macro shenanigans to count arguments and dispatch at compile-time if you require such an interface.

Comment: But I am sure someone will show up and refer to the standard that explains this.

Comment: Note that functions like `printf()` know how many arguments are passed because the format string tells them how many were passed.  The system call `open()` sometimes has three arguments; it knows based on whether `O_CREAT` is set in the second argument.  Similarly with any other varargs function — there must be a way to know whether (and how many) variable arguments were passed on a given call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling `va_arg` for a non-existent argument is Undefined Behavior, so you could get a garbage value, a crash, or anything at all.  A varargs function *must* know the number and types of its variadic arguments.